# How to build jasper parameterized queries which are not-required fields

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to jasper reports , I want to build a report which takes few fields among them few are required and few not required fields. I ran a sample report in jasper studio which has single parameter . how can I mention such non required parameters in the query . Required parameter can be mentioned as below

```
Select * from member where first_name=$P{param_name};
```

Is there any way to put non-required fields in that query. Or else should I use if else conditions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have handled it in the past.  In your `WHERE` clause, check to see if the paramter is NULL (in which you would return all records), or your `WHERE` condition.

```
Select  * 
from    member 
where  ($P{param_name} IS NULL OR first_name = $P{param_name});
```

Comment: no it didn't work for me, i tried 
select * from orders where ($P{shipcity} IS NULL OR SHIPCITY=$P{shipcity}) in my case report didn't run. it still promoting me to enter that field.

Comment: What if you try ($P{shipcity} = '' OR SHIPCITY=$P{shipcity}) ?

Comment: no same result, still prompting me to enter the param. i am using jasper studio